# Update data in jquery (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Just started learn Ajax. You nedeet to edit the data this that I get from the server. I receive them, fill in the input, and how to save (change) I do not understand, I can only add as a new record .. but it needs to be edited.

```js
 $('.edit-table').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
         $('#modal-1').modal();
         $('.btn-form').css({
             'display': 'none'
         });
         $('.btn-form-save').css({
             'display': 'inline-block'
         });
         
         $.ajax({
            url:'/api/v1/education/direction_info/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                'id': id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = data[0];
//                debugger;
                for (key in obj) {
                    console.log(key, obj[key])
                    
                    
                    
                   if(key.indexOf('image') != -1) {
                       $("form[name='form03'] [name='" + key + "']").attr('value', obj[key]);
                   } else { 
                       $("form[name='form03'] [name='" + key + "']").val(obj[key]);
                   }
                }
                
            }
        }); 
     });
```

```html
<table class="table" data-token="{{ csrf_token }}">
                                 <thead class="table-inverse">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Направление</th>
                                        <th>Руководитель</th>
                                        <th>Кол-во программ</th>
                                        <th>Кол-во слушателей</th>
                                        <th>
                                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-1" class="btn btn-primary mrg-b-lg  pull-right  add-prod  js-direct">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>Add product</a>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                 </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                     {% for obj in object_list %}
                                        <tr data-href="{{ obj.url }}">
                                            <td>{{ obj.pk }}</td>
                                            <td><a href="{{ obj.get_lk_url }}">{{ obj.name }}</a></td>
                                            <td>{{ obj.director }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ obj.get_courses_count }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ obj.get_students_count }}</td>
                                            <td class="td-center">
                                           <a href="#" class="table-link  edit-table  js-direct" data-id="{{ obj.pk }}">
                                            <span class="fa-stack">
                                                <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                            </span>
                                           </a>
                                            <a href="#" class="table-link danger  unistall-table  js-direct" data-id="{{ obj.pk }}">
                                                <span class="fa-stack">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                
                                <form role="form" name="form03" class="form-list" data-token="{{ csrf_token }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name1">Направление</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="name1" name="name" placeholder="Введите направление">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="sort1">Сортировка</label>
       <input type="number" class="form-control" id="sort1" name="sort" min=1 max=100 placeholder="Введите число от 1 до 100">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="check1">Архив</label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="archived" id="check1">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="image1">image</label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image1">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="instructor_image">instructor_page_image</label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control" name="instructor_page_image" id="instructor_image">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="popular">Популярность</label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="popular" id="popular">
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="director1">Директор</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="director" id="director1">
                                
                            </select>
      </div>
      
     </form>
```

Comment: what is your prob:?

Comment: You need to either create another ajax call to put changes back to the server or wrap your table with a form and submit to an action controller.

Comment: @user7417866 My large problem: How is to save the edited data?

Comment: @DaveClough if I create ajax call, how can I transfer the changed data?

Comment: @b-ars07 It could be useful to read about the CRUD operations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete from what I read in your question I think it might be useful to learn about these while you're learning AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have another ajax call similar as you are having first one..

```
  $.ajax({
        url:[Server URL] - This will be server URL to receive parameter you send into data.
        type: 'POST', -- you need to have post when you send data to server
        data: { // your edited data will go here...
        },
        success: function (data) {
}
})
```

Comment: similar way as you can set the data into  $("form[name='form03'] [name='" + key + "']").val(obj[key]); you can get the edited data  $("form[name='form03'] [name='" + key + "']").val();

Comment: its jst the way you could get data, you need to check for proper ID of your element to get edited data.

Comment: you might like to have some tutorial first on how to get data from JQuery